# How to make dropbox authenticate a popup instead of redirect

Tags: javascript, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using Dropbox JavaScript SDK and authenticating the user so I'd get an oauth token. The problem is that when using the `client.authenticate()`, the user gets redirected to Dropbox instead of a popup. How can it be changed to a popup instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-js/blob/stable/guides/builtin_drivers.md.

```
client.authDriver(new Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup({
    receiverUrl: "https://url.to/oauth_receiver.html"}));
```

and run this in your oauth_receiver.html:

```
Dropbox.AuthDriver.Popup.oauthReceiver();
```

Comment: The link is broken.